# useState initialValue function called on every rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why function `getSth` is called (can see `console.log`s) every time component rerenders (by changing `isSth` value on button click) although it isn't changing the `randomValue` state?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function getSth() {
  console.log('init');
  return Math.random();
}

function Home() {
  const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState(getSth());
  const [isSth, setIsSth] = useState(false);

  console.log(randomValue);

  const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setIsSth((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

but when I do this, `getSth` is actually called once?

```
  const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    getSth();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial value is only set on the 1st render, so even if the function is called multiple times, only the 1st result is used.

Pass the `getSth` function (without the `()`) to `useState`, so it would be treated as initializer function:

```
const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState(getSth); // remove () from getSth
```

According to the React docs:

> If you pass a function as initialState, it will be treated as an
> initializer function. It should be pure, should take no arguments, and
> should return a value of any type. React will call your initializer
> function when initializing the component, and store its return value
> as the initial state.

Initializer function is only called once. See [Avoiding recreating the initial state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state).